# How to make T-flip-flop into an 8 bit counter?

Tags: vhdl

I have this code for a t-flip flop :

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
entity tff is
Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
enable : in STD_LOGIC;
t : in STD_LOGIC;
q : out STD_LOGIC);
end tff;
architecture Behavioral of tff is
signal q_reg: std_logic;
signal q_next: std_logic;
begin
process(clk)
begin
if (enable = '1') then
q_reg <= '0'; elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then q_reg <= q_next;
end if;
end process;
q_next <= q_reg when t = '0' else not(q_reg);
q <= q_reg;
end Behavioral;
```

and I'm wondering if someone can show me how to design an 8 bit counter from it?

Thanks

EDIT: Schematic I am working from:
[image]

Comment: Can you include a schematic for the 8-bit counter you want to build using the T-flip-flop? That would help with your design and be less likely to piss people off since you appear to have done no work yourself towards completing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `tff` `enable` is actual expressed as an asynchronous reset although it is not in the process sensitivity list.

The actual enable is the `t` input (toggle enable) which controls the multiplexer you connected in front of a D flipflop.  You could make it a synchronous reset, I left it as an asynchronous reset in the following.

Fixing the reset name and process sensitivity list:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tff is
    port (
        clk:    in  std_logic;
        reset:  in  std_logic;
        t:      in  std_logic;
        q:      out std_logic
    );
end entity tff;

architecture behavioral of tff is
    signal q_reg:   std_logic;
    signal q_next:  std_logic;
begin

T_FF:
    process (clk, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            q_reg <= '0'; 
        elsif rising_edge(clk)  then 
            q_reg <= q_next;
        end if;
    end process;

INPUT_MUX:    
    q_next <=     q_reg  when t = '0' else 
              not q_reg;
OUTPUT:
    q  <= q_reg;

end architecture;
```

This is all just applied style other than the sensitivity list element and the name.

Creating an eight bit counter from the `tff`:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tff_counter is
    port (
        clk:    in  std_logic;
        reset:  in  std_logic;
        en:     in  std_logic;
        q:      out std_logic_vector
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of tff_counter is
    component tff is
        port (
            clk:    in  std_logic;
            reset:  in  std_logic;
            t:      in  std_logic;
            q:      out std_logic
        );
    end component;

    signal cnt:         std_logic_vector (0 to 7);
    signal t:           std_logic_vector (0 to 7); 
begin

    -- The seven AND gates:
    t <=  (              en,   en and cnt(0), t(1) and cnt(1), t(2) and cnt(2),
            t(3) and cnt(3), t(4) and cnt(4), t(5) and cnt(5), t(6) and cnt(6)
          );

--  The eight TFFs:
TFF_0:
    component tff
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            reset => reset,
            t => t(0),
            q => cnt(0)
        ); 

TFF_1:
    component tff
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            reset => reset,
            t => t(1),
            q => cnt(1)
        ); 

TFF_2:
    component tff
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            reset => reset,
            t => t(2),
            q => cnt(2)
        ); 

TFF_3:
    component tff
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            reset => reset,
            t => t(3),
            q => cnt(3)
        );       

TFF_4:
    component tff
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            reset => reset,
            t => t(4),
            q => cnt(4)
        ); 

TFF_5:
    component tff
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            reset => reset,
            t => t(5),
            q => cnt(5)
        ); 

TFF_6:
    component tff
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            reset => reset,
            t => t(6),
            q => cnt(6)
        ); 

TFF_7:
    component tff
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            reset => reset,
            t => t(7),
            q => cnt(7)
        );

-- The eight TFFs can be expressed with a generate statement instead of individually: 
--
-- COUNTER_GEN:
--     for i in cnt'range generate
-- T_FF:
--         component tff
--             port map (
--                 clk => clk,
--                 reset => reset,
--                 t => t(i),
--                 q => cnt(i)
--             );
--     end generate;

    q <= cnt;

end architecture;
```

Note the and gates are shown in an aggregate assignment to an array expressing all eight `t` inputs to the flip flops.

This is to allow the use of a generate statement (shown, commented out), which could be used in place of `TFF_0` through `TFF_7` as shown.

To use the output of the counter arithmetically you'd want to change the `to` order to `downto` for the declared `t` and `cnt` std_logic_vector signals.  (I accidentally left the subtype constraint off the the output port `q` declaration, it happens to work).  The idea was to preserve the left right order matching the schematic.

You'd also want to reverse the order of positional associations in the aggregate assigning the std_logic_vector `t` or use named association. I was mostly interested in fitting it in as few a lines as practical with some applied style, they could be individual assignments.

Throw in a testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tff_counter_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of tff_counter_tb is
    signal clk:     std_logic := '1';
    signal reset:   std_logic;
    signal en:      std_logic;
    signal q:       std_logic_vector (0 to 7);
begin
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 5 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 2600 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
DUT:
    entity work. tff_counter
        port map (
            clk   => clk,
            reset => reset,
            en    => en,
            q     => q    
        );
STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 6 ns;
        reset <= '1';
        en <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        reset <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        en <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        en <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        en <= '1';
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

And you get:

[image: tff_counter_tb.png]

The A marker shows the asynchronous reset taking effect (because the reset was added to the `tff` process sensitivity list).

The B marker shows the enable works.

Adding on fingers and toes and we can see we can add 40 ns to the 256 counter increments and find the counter rollover:

[image: tff_counter_tb_rollover]

Answer (score 0):

You now have an entity to use for each flip flop. That is a definition of the flip flop. You need to declare four of them, which you can do using a port map. mytffmap: tff port map(whatever you need to connect);
You will have a port map for each flip flop, and the things to connect are what you connect in and out of the different flip flops. In doing this, you now have four flip flops with connections. I will assume you know what a signal is and therefore you know what to pass in and out.